# PSQL determine the min value of date depending on another column

Tags: sql, postgresql, data-partitioning

The input table looks like this:

| ID | pid | method | date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 111 | A123 | credit_card | 12-03-2015 |
| 111 | A128 | ACH | 11-28-2015 |

Now for the `ID = 111`, I need to select the `MIN(date)` and see what the method of payment for it is. I need the output table to be as follows:

| ID. | method | date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 111 | ACH | 11-28-2015 |

I've tried using a window function to get the minimum date and use a `LEAD` in the subquery, still does not give me what I want.

```
WITH fd AS( 
    SELECT DISTINCT ID, 
                    method , 
                   (MIN(date) OVER(PARTITION BY method)) AS first_dt 
    FROM table 
    WHERE id = 111
) 
SELECT DISTINCT fd.ID, 
                method, 
                LEAD(first_dt) OVER(ORDER BY fd.ID) AS first_method 
FROM fd
```

Can anyone please help me with this?

Comment: can you share the query you mention? maybe it just needs some quick fix @koimoi

Comment: with fd as( 
 select 
  distinct ID,
  method ,
  (min(date)over (partition by method) )as first_dt
 from table  
 where id = 111
 )
 
 select distinct fd.ID ,
 method,
 lead(first_dt) over (order by fd.ID) as first_method
 from fd

Comment: Can you tell the reason of using the `LEAD` window function? Is there a requirement not specified in the post? Also how do you choose the value for the `method` field? @koimoi

Comment: Yes this table had multiple IDs and I need the min date and the corresponding method for all the IDs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alternate solution, prompted by Cignitor's [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72594619/psql-determine-the-min-value-of-date-depending-on-another-column/72595310#comment134406574_72595310).

We can use the `FIRST_VALUE` function to get the first value of any particular column subject to any defined window. In this case, we want to consider each ID separately so we partition on that column, and we want to consider the 'first' element when ordering by date.

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT
    ID
  , FIRST_VALUE(method) OVER w
  , FIRST_VALUE(date) OVER w
FROM tab
WINDOW w AS (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY date)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can solve your problem with the window function `ROW_NUMBER`, that will assign a unique number to each of your rows. Since you want:

- only one row for each "*ID*", then you can use the `PARTITION BY` clause on "*ID*"
- the first "*date*", then you can use the `ORDER BY` clause on "*date*" ascendently

Once you get this ranking value, the rows to retrieve (for each "*ID*") will be the ones that have rank = 1 (the lowest "*date*" for each partition).

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER(
               PARTITION BY ID 
               ORDER     BY date
           ) AS rn
    FROM tab
)
SELECT ID, 
       pid,
       method, 
       date
FROM cte 
WHERE rn = 1
```

Check the demo [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/uXNp1ouJRXXqJ1ABep2PEj/0).

Comment: is there any functions that works like `min() over(partition by columns)` ?